# No, I don't want persistent net rules

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I have a bootable Linux memstick that I use on a lot of different PCs (but all of the same model and configuration). Trouble is that udev is renaming the eth interfaces so that what was `eth0` on the last PC is suddenly ethX, where X=1..inf. This causes if-up (called by ifplugd) to fail, since `/etc/network/interfaces` only specifies how to bring up `eth0`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

It's a well-known problem; I've googled and found that this is caused by the MAC addresses changing and that it may be fixed by deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. But that only works after a reboot, which is inconvenient and should be unneccessary, since I know what behaviour I want.

What I want is *non-persistent* net rules, or in the alternative, an `/etc/network/interfaces` script that adapts to the changing eth names, or perhaps it can be done with ifplugd. What's the best way to achieve this?

Distro: Ubuntu 8.04.

Comment: 8.04 is no longer supported on the desktop; upgrade to at least 10.04.  You will probably find this issue is fixed there also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The persistent net rules are generated by `/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules` (or something similar, I'm looking on a newer Debian machine).

If Ubuntu 8.04 still has that generator script in /etc/udev/rules.d, you can just get rid of it.

Otherwise, I believe putting a blank file in /etc/udev/rules.d will override the one in /lib.

You could also write your own rules file to give the interface a name—the persistent rules generator ignores the interface if a name has already been set.

Answer (score 2):

I followed derobert's advice, deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules`, and also I edited the already generated `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` so that the lines looked like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="%k"
```

Note the `%k` in `NAME`, which means to use the kernel name.